# How to "merge" 2 functions (const & non-const i/o) into one?

Tags: c++, constants, polymorphism, overloading, function-templates-overloading

Is there a syntax for merging the following 2 functions into one, so that if input is `const`, result is `const`, and if input is non-const, result is non-const?

```
char* f1(char* x) {
    return x+1;
}

const char* f2(const char* x) {
    return x+1;
}
```

Comment: There probably are, but it will be more complicated than plain overloading.

Comment: If you can use C++23, this might help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/ It may well be that only MSVC implements this at this stage.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/M8hP3v5WG) ? But it doesn't seem to be more readable than simply using to different functions.

Comment: You can use a template function like 
template <typename T>
T foo(T x) {
    return x + 1;
}

Comment: **Unrelated:** Except if called with pointers to array elements (and not the last), these functions open the door to Undefined Behaviour if such an invalid pointer is ever dereferenced.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude unless they state otherwise, I would assume that OP is looking for overloading. I first misread that this would be already the case, but they have `f1` and `f2`

Comment: btw your wording suggests that you confuse `const char *` with `char * const`. In your both functions `x` itself is not `const` and constness of the parameter passed to them doesnt matter

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, sorry, I am not confusing the two, just the wording was not very good, I mean a pointer to const, the other way around is, as you say, not of interest...

Answer (score 4):

This

```
char* f1(char* x) {
    return x+1;
}

const char* f1(const char* x) {   // rename f2->f1
    return x+1;
}
```

Does not make it "one function", but it is one set of overloads and for the user it shouldnt matter that it actually is more than one function unless they try to take the address.

There are ways to avoid duplication of the implementation, perhaps the most simple is to implement the non-const overload in terms of the const one:

```
const char* f1(const char* x) {
    return x+1;
}

char* f1(char* x) {
    return const_cast<char*>(f1(static_cast<const char*>(x)));
}
```

In the second overload `x` points to a non-const `char`, hence it is ok to cast away the constness from result of the other overload.

Comment: this technique is especially useful when proving const and non-const accessors in a class.  Lets you keep you code DRY bay calling the const version in the non-const version.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a function template as shown below:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T *ptr)
requires(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<T>, char>)
{
    return ptr+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple template:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
T* f(T* p)
{
    return p + 1;
}


int main()
{
    // const char pointer:
    const char cca[]{ "Hello" };
    const char* ccp{ f(cca) };
    std::cout << *ccp << std::endl; // 'e'
    
    // char pointer:
    char ca[6]{ "World" };
    char* cp{ f(ca) };
    std::cout << *cp << std::endl; // 'o'
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/vf0WlJxrm)